# How do I convert my 3D models and animations into Virtual reality content so that anyone can view it in 360 degree perspective?

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, export, add-on

I want to create some entertaining and informational content that anyone can watch in a VR headset that's why I want to know how to convert my 3D models as well as animations into 3D 360 degree viewable format!!

Comment: Did you tried https://sketchfab.com/ ?

Comment: If you know a little of programming, you could export your model using Blender's gltf exporter (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO). In blender 2.80 it is already included. Then, you could import these models in A-frame (https://aframe.io/), a really basic and simple framework for virual reality web-applications. Doing so gives you much more freedom than importing your models in sketchfab

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer.I really appreciate it. @RAGE